# print statement delays printing when followed by comma

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, if I use print statement followed by comma as the following:

```
print('Generation ...'),
X, y = generate_dataset(num_samples)
print('Done!')
```

The first print `print('Generation ...'),` will NOT show up in the terminal until `X, y = generate_dataset(num_samples)` is finished! How can I force the print to immediately step by step with the existence of comma?

Comment: you cannot do it, if you keep comma print statement will wait until x,y are evaluated and only then print statement can show the result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print You'll probably have to manually flush output. Comma is not exactly relevant here since print is a side effect that doesn't need to wait for evaluation results.

Comment: `print "aaa",inf_loop()` does print to screen before I hit Ctrl+C in Jupyter notebook and `print "aa", sys.stdout.flush(), inf_loop()` does print to screen in interactive python shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

print "I'm going to do something that takes a long time...",
sys.stdout.flush()
really_time_consuming_function()
print "done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the python interpreter with the `-u` flag if you don't want to handle this in code.